Dependency injection in Nestjs is working on the controller but no the service
I'm working on an existing NestJS project with TypeORM to manage a PostgreSQL database. I have a ReclamoService in a ReclamoModule that I want to use in the UsuariosService of a UsuariosModule.
When I try to inject ReclamoService into UsuariosService, my application breaks and asks me to import ReclamoModule. However, injecting ReclamoService into a controller works fine. I have exported the ReclamoService from its module and imported the ReclamoModule in UsuariosModule.
Here are the relevant parts of my code:
module with the service i am exporting
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ReclamoService } from './reclamo.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Reclamo } from './entities/reclamo.entity';
import { DependenciaModule } from 'src/dependencia/dependencia.module';
import { BeneficiarioModule } from 'src/beneficiario/beneficiario.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Reclamo]),
    DependenciaModule,
    BeneficiarioModule,
  ],
  providers: [ReclamoService],
  exports: [ReclamoService],
})
export class ReclamoModule {}

second module importing the previous one
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsuariosService } from './usuarios.service';
import { UsuariosController } from './usuarios.controller';
import { UsuariosEntity } from './entities/usuarios.entity';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UsuariosPermisosService } from '../auth/services/usuarios_permisos.service';
import { PerfilesPermisosService } from '../auth/services/perfiles_permisos.service';
import { AuthService } from 'src/auth/services/auth.service';
import { LogEntity } from 'src/auth/entities/log.entity';
import { UtilsService } from 'src/utils/utils.service';
import { SecurityService } from 'src/security/security.service';
import { ReclamoModule } from 'src/reclamo/reclamo.module';
import { MenuModule } from 'src/menu/menu.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MenuModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      // LogEntity,
      UsuariosEntity,
    ]),
    ReclamoModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    UsuariosService,
    UsuariosPermisosService,
    PerfilesPermisosService,
    AuthService,
    UtilsService,
    SecurityService,
  ],
  controllers: [UsuariosController],
  exports: [UsuariosModule, TypeOrmModule],
})
export class UsuariosModule {}

Service
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UsuariosEntity } from './entities/usuarios.entity';
import { UsuariosPermisosEntity } from '../auth/entities/usuarios_permisos.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { ErrorManager } from 'src/utils/error.manager';
import {
  AsignarReclamosDto,
  UsuarioDTO,
  guardarUsuarioDTO,
  iniSizeDTO,
} from './dtos/usuario.dto';
import {
  intfc_GuardarDataUsuarioPermisos,
} from 'src/usuarios/interfaces/usuarios.interface';
import { UtilsService } from 'src/utils/utils.service';
import { UsuariosPermisosService } from 'src/auth/services/usuarios_permisos.service';
import { ReclamoService } from 'src/reclamo/reclamo.service';

@Injectable()
export class UsuariosService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UsuariosEntity)
    private userRepository: Repository<UsuariosEntity>,

    @InjectRepository(UsuariosPermisosEntity)
    private usuarioPermisoRepository: Repository<UsuariosPermisosEntity>,

    private readonly util: UtilsService,

    @Inject('REQUEST') private req: Request,

    private readonly userPermisosService: UsuariosPermisosService,
     private readonly reclamoService: ReclamoService, // when i comment this line the code stops breaking
  ) {}
  ...
}

controller (works fine with the imported service)
import {
  Req,
  Body,
  Controller,
  Get,
  Param,
  Post,
  UseGuards,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsuariosService } from './usuarios.service';
import { ApiHeader, ApiOperation, ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { TokenGuard } from 'src/auth/guards/token.guard';
import {
  AsignarReclamosDto,
  // UsuarioDTO,
  guardarUsuarioDTO,
  iniSizeDTO,
} from './dtos/usuario.dto';
import { AuthGuard } from 'src/auth/guards/auth.guard';
import { PermisosAccess } from 'src/auth/decorators/permisos.decorator';
import { MenuAccess } from 'src/auth/decorators/menus.decorator';
import { MENUS } from 'src/constants/menus';
import { ReclamoService } from 'src/reclamo/reclamo.service';

@Controller('users')
@ApiHeader({ name: 'token', description: 'description' })
@UseGuards(TokenGuard, AuthGuard)
export class UsuariosController {
  constructor(
    private readonly userService: UsuariosService,
    private readonly reclamoService: ReclamoService,
  ) {}
  ...
}

The Error
[Nest] 244433  - 05/31/2024, 11:23:01 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsuariosService (UsuariosEntityRepository, UsuariosPermisosEntityRepository, UtilsService, REQUEST, UsuariosPermisosService, ?). Please make sure that the argument ReclamoService at index [5] is available in the MenuModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is MenuModule a valid NestJS module?
- If ReclamoService is a provider, is it part of the current MenuModule?
- If ReclamoService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within MenuModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ReclamoService */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsuariosService (UsuariosEntityRepository, UsuariosPermisosEntityRepository, UtilsService, REQUEST, UsuariosPermisosService, ?). Please make sure that the argument ReclamoService at index [5] is available in the MenuModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is MenuModule a valid NestJS module?
- If ReclamoService is a provider, is it part of the current MenuModule?
- If ReclamoService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within MenuModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ReclamoService */ ]
  })

Aditional Details

I am new to Nestjs
The Service is working correctly in the UsuariosController

Expectations

If you could provide an explanation of why the app breakes when injecting the ReclamosService in the UsuariosService.
Guidance on the correct way to import and inject services across modules in NestJS


have you tried:
@Module({
  imports: [
    MenuModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      // LogEntity,
      UsuariosEntity,
    ]),
    ReclamoModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    UsuariosService,
    UsuariosPermisosService,
    PerfilesPermisosService,
    AuthService,
    UtilsService,
    SecurityService,
    ReclamoService // provide ReclamoService here

  ],
  controllers: [UsuariosController],
  exports: [UsuariosModule, TypeOrmModule],
})
export class UsuariosModule {}


Just tried adding the service too but the issue persists, it even throws an error about a different module(MenuModule), but the service and module I am trying to inject has no relation to that MenuModule

@EduardoSerrano if possible can you provide repository link? it's easier to solve these issues when you can take a look at the codebase.

Thank you for offering to help! I was finally able to resolve the issue.
The problem was that the application was setting up all the entities and repositories for each module/service across the entire app. In many modules, they were exporting the entire module instead of just the necessary services. Additionally, when a service was needed, instead of importing the module containing the service, they were declaring the services again as providers.
After fixing these issues, I was able to import the service I needed.
